# How to customize Cucumber TestNG for the different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, cucumber, testng

I need to implement parallel execution of cucumber features and, obviously, set up them for the different threads.

So, I created two features, classes, and one `TestNgRuner` for the .XML execution.
There is a project structure:

```
src/
└── test/
    └── java/
        └── com/
            └── projectname/
                └── tests/
                    ├── TestRunner.java
                    ├── suites/
                    │   ├── first/
                    │   │   └── FirstSteps.java
                    │   └── second/
                    │       └── SecondSteps.java
                    └── resources/
                        └── suites/
                            └── smoke.xml
```

Parallel execution ensured by `smoke.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Test Debug" parallel="tests">
    <test name="Test 1">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
        <parameter name="cucumber.features" value="classpath:features/first"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.projectname.tests.TestRunner"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test 2">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
        <parameter name="cucumber.features" value="classpath:features/second"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.projectname.tests.TestRunner"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

So, you can guess, I need to establish WebDriver according to the `browser` parameter, and this establishment has to be executed for each `test`. So, as I understand, I have to use testing `@BeforeTest` annotation in the `TestRunner` class, since exactly this class managed and execute `@Test` methods (through `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests` extension):

- TestRunner:

```java
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    private static volatile ThreadLocal<String> threadLocal;
    private static String debug;

    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void init(@Optional("chrome") String browser) {
        System.out.println("BrowserName: " + browser);
        printThread(browser);
        if (threadLocal == null) {
            synchronized (TestRunner.class) {
                if (threadLocal == null) {
                    threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();
                }
            }
        }
        threadPool.set(browser);
        debug = browser;
    }

    public static String getBrowserName(){
        return threadPool.get(); ------------- > line 2
    }

    public static String getDebugString(){
        return debug;// ---------------------- > line 3
    }
}
```

I was sure, with this solution, I will receive different threads for each `test` and `static` fields will be common for them, but it has occurred that **line 1** executed 2 times. Ok, for this case I can establish browser for each thread without `ThreadLocal` using I thought...but the `debug` parameter initialized also 2 times, and in the both cases, when I called `getDebugString` (**line 3**) I receive the last value that was initialized. In this point I need to say I call `getDebugString()` in the `FirstSteps.class` and `SecondSteps.class`:

- `FirsSteps`:

```java
public class FirstSteps  {

    @When("First Step")
    public void firstStep() throws InterruptedException {
        TestRunner.printThread();
        System.out.println("FirstSteps::firstStep");
        System.out.println("FirstSteps thread parameter: " + TestRunner.getBrowserName()); // ------------ line 1
        System.out.println("FirstSteps Debug parameter: " + TestRunner.getDebugParameter()); // ---------- line 2
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }

    @Then("Second Step")
    public void secondStep() {
        System.out.println("FirstSteps::secondStep");
    }
}
```

In the **line 1** I receive `null` value.
In the **line 2** I receive **the same value for both cases** - the value that was initialized in the first queue (if the first test was with parameter **browser=chrome** - it will be **chrome** for both the `FirstSteps` and `SecondSteps`, otherwise - **firefox**

- `SecondSteps`:

```java
public class SecondSteps extends BaseApi {
    @When("First Function")
    public void firstFunction() throws InterruptedException {
        TestRunner.printThread();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("SecondSteps::firstFunction");
        System.out.println("SecondSteps thread parameter: " + TestRunner.getBrowserName());
        System.out.println("SecondSteps debug parameter: " + TestRunner.getDebugParameter());
    }

    @Then("Second Function")
    public void secondFunction() {
        System.out.println("SecondSteps::secondFunction");
    }
}
```

So, it seems the `static` field is common for both threads! But why is the `ThreadLocal` not working in this case??

---

Console output:

```
FirstSteps::firstStep
FirstSteps thread parameter: null
FirstSteps Debug parameter: chrome
SecondSteps::firstFunction
SecondSteps thread parameter: null
SecondSteps debug parameter: chrome
SecondSteps::secondFunction
FirstSteps::secondStep
```

- **Update**

After I added `printThread();` function that print *{$THREAD_NAME}-{$THREAD_ID} {$ADDITION_INFO}* I received following console log:

```
BrowserName: chrome
BrowserName: firefox
com.projectname.tests.TestRunner::init - TestNG-tests-2-18 for firefox
com.projectname.tests.TestRunner::init - TestNG-tests-1-17 for chrome
FirstSteps::secondStep
FirstSteps::firstStep
com.projectname.tests.suites.second.SecondSteps::firstFunction - TestNG-PoolService-0-20
FirstSteps thread parameter: null
FirstSteps Debug parameter: chrome
com.projectname.tests.suites.first.FirstSteps::firstStep - TestNG-PoolService-0-21
SecondSteps::firstFunction
SecondSteps thread parameter: null
SecondSteps debug parameter: chrome
SecondSteps::secondFunction
```

So, as I understand - the `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests` executes tests in a separate threads (some `PoolService` threads). I'll research this behavior, but anyway, I left this answer here, until I haven't solution.

PS. Still is so weird the fact that TestNG creates two new threads with the FIRST instance of the class (I mean instance with 'chrome' browser for `debug` field). And so weird, that cucumber works so ugly...

Comment: Can you print out the names of the threads with each print systemen? Also put the same print statements in the `@BeforeTest` method.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Good point! I had updated the answer. I will be grateful if you help.

Comment: Mmh. Bit hard to type it all out right now. Perhaps you can  override the run method in the runner class and . use the parameter annotation on that. I usually use the conditional hooks in Cucumber in combination with multiple executions in CI. One for each browser.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Good to know I may ask someone about cucumber. This framework is crack all my imaging of automation project architecture. All that I know about TestNG - is useless now :)

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje First of all I understood - that parallel execution isn't possible in the cucumber from the TestNG.xml. And it seems it does not a good idea to execute parallel tests in cucumber with different parameters. I seems the single-type tests with the same environment (the same browser, same cookies, settings, etc..) are possible, not more.  I had tried @BeforAll hook - also not working totally: I even receive NullPointerException for `threadPool` field. At least not so weird! - now one thread doesn't initialize the same instance for both thread :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because TestNG runs the tests from the `@DataProvider` method on a different thread then the `@BeforeClass` method, you have to pass the parameter around a bit differently. Instead of setting the value on a thread local during the before class step, it has to be set just before the scenario is executed.

You can do this by inlining the `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests` class.

```java
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberPropertiesProvider;
import io.cucumber.testng.FeatureWrapper;
import io.cucumber.testng.PickleWrapper;
import io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "html:target/results.html", "message:target/results.ndjson" }) // Not really needed you can run entirely through the XML, just for example.
public abstract class CustomTestNGCucumberTests {

    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;
    private final ThreadLocal<String> browser = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private XmlTest currentXmlTest;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass(ITestContext context) {
        // Here we put the current context in the test class. 
        // This context is distinct for each class so classes can
        // run in parallel.
        currentXmlTest = context.getCurrentXmlTest();

        CucumberPropertiesProvider properties = currentXmlTest::getParameter;
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass(), properties);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void runScenario(PickleWrapper pickleWrapper, FeatureWrapper featureWrapper) {
        // Then here we make the value of browser parameter available
        // to the tests on the same thread. Because we are picking this value
        // from the class, it should work when multiple classes run in parallel.
        browser.set(currentXmlTest.getParameter("browser"));
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleWrapper.getPickle());
    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = true) // This make Cucumber run scenarios in parallel
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        if (testNGCucumberRunner == null) {
            return new Object[0][0];
        }
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() {
        if (testNGCucumberRunner == null) {
            return;
        }
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }

}
```

Note: I didn't test this.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But now the problem is that the threads don't execute in parallel mode - yes, we have two different threads, but they running one after the other.

Comment: Which ones? For the classes or the scenarios from the ` @DataProvider(parallel = true)` method. You'll have to configure the `dataproviderthreadcount` somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, I had mistaken - I had experimented with an XML file and forgot to add paralleling there. It seems now all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess:

The check `threadPool == null` is prone to race conditions. Both threads may see that `threadPool` is `null` and overwrite it.

You can initialize it when you define the field.

```
private static ThreadLocal<String> threadPool = new ThreadLocal<>();
```

You should also change the name of the variable, thread pools and thread locals are very different things.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, this isn't the reason for the behavior. But I'll consider your point and update initializing to the threadsafe way.